# Connection to a MySQL server fails after server restart

Tags: mysql, network, connections

Until this morning I could connect via Sequel Pro to one of our networked machines that has the MySQL server on it.

Today, however, it's another story: when I am trying to connect, it times out. Even if I start a simple PHP PDO connection and run it from my machine it returns "504 gateway time out".

It's been set up for years and the details are simple:

```
HOST: 192.168.1.4 -- 
DB: ??? -- 
PW: ???? -- 
PORT: 3306 --
```

etc. I have not changed or edited any users.

Now the only thing that happened overnight was we had a power cut and this machine was restarted, so I am not sure if this could have caused the issue, because I have restarted the machine many times and it also has done so automatically with updates etc.

And after trying what I could find I am stuck, at what I can do next.

Your advise would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local Server Firewall settings.

in my case the local server was using McAfee, so enabling the port 3306 access to all pc's fixed the issue.